# Задача с страницами книги

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика

Есть задача, я ее правильно решил, но на одном из тестов выдает "Time limit error". Перепробовал самые различные варианты решения этой задачи, в том числе написать отдельную функцию которая бы просто делила на 10 и возвращала количество делений (количество цифр на странице), но она всегда падает на тесте с большим количеством вводных данных. Вот сама задача.

> Девочка рисует книжки. Каждую книгу она нумерует с X числа. Иными словами, на первой странице есть номер X, написанный на нем, на второй странице есть номер X + 1, написанный на нем, и так далее. Она использовала общее количество цифр, равное N, и начал нумерацию книжек с номера X. Пример: номер 99 имеет 2 цифры на нем. Поэтому, если бы я написал только 2 страницы, начиная с номера 99, я бы использовал 5 цифр для номера моей комиксов: 99, 101.
>
> **Вводные данные:** Первая строка содержит целое число T, количество тестовых случаев. Каждая строка из следующих T строк описывает один тестовый пример. Каждый тестовый пример содержит 2 пробела, разделенных целыми числами N, X (1 ≤ N, X ≤ 10^15).
>
> **Вывод:** Для каждого тестового примера печатайте одну строку, содержащую одно целое число, обозначающее количество страниц в комиксе Nour или печатайте -1, если такое невозможно.
>
> **Примеры Ввода/Вывода:**
>
> ```
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | стандартный ввод | стандартный вывод |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> | 2                | 8                 |
> | 11 5             | -1                |
> | 12 5             |                   |
> +------------------+-------------------+
> ```

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    string s;
    int x1, t, len, lap=0;
    long long int n, x;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        cin >> n >> x;
        s = to_string(x);
        len = s.length();
        x1=x%10;
        while(n>0)
        {
            if(x1%10==0 && lap>0){len++;}
            n-=len;
            lap++;
            x1++;
        }
        if(n==0){cout << lap << endl;}
        else{cout << "-1"<<endl;}
        lap = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"тестовый пример содержит 2 пробела, разделенных целыми числами"* Угу. Можно оригинальный текст задания? Тот, что в вопросе, выглядит как из гугл переводчика.

Comment: Не понял. Почему 2 страницы - это "99,101", а не "99, 100"?

Comment: @AnT 99 это две цифры 9 и 9, а 100 еще три 1 и два 0.

Comment: Еще раз: почему у вас в условии написано, что 2 страницы - это "99, **101**", а не "99, **100**"? Почему вы пропустили 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вряд ли идея подсчитывать все страницы, пока не кончатся цифры, подойдёт для больших чисел. Лучше подумать о более быстром решении, использующем немножко логики и математики.

Все страницы от `first`, номер которых не превосходит следующую степень десяти `tenpow`, содержат одинаковое количество цифр `ndig`.

Таким образом, можно проверить, истратим ли мы все имеющиеся цифры `nd` в пределах `tenpow`.
Если да, то нужно убедиться, что не будет остатка.

Если же нет, то уменьшаем `nd` на количество цифр в данном диапазоне и переходим к следующему диапазону.

Сложность решения логарифмическая `O(log(nd))`

(Замечу, что мой третий пример подсказывает идею ещё более быстрого решения, но вряд ли это уже понадобится)

```
def pages(nd, first):
    tenpow = 1
    ndig = 0
    t = first
    while t > 0:
        t = t // 10
        tenpow *= 10
        ndig += 1

    sum = 0

    last = first - 1 + nd // ndig
    while last >= tenpow:
        sum += tenpow - first
        nd -= (tenpow - first) * ndig
        first = tenpow
        tenpow *= 10
        ndig += 1
        last = first - 1 + nd // ndig

    if nd % ndig > 0:
        return -1
    return sum + (last - first + 1)

print(pages(117, 88))
print(pages(118, 88))
print(pages(7*1 + 90 * 2 + 900 * 3 + 9000 * 4 + 33333 * 5, 3))
print(pages(2000000*7 + 66666666 * 8, 8000000))

43
-1
43330
68666666
```

Comment: def это тип функции? я просто не знаю def, знаю только #define. можно заменить def на int этот тип тоже возвращает значение?

Comment: просто с int выдает неправильные значения. В тестах выдает 11 и -1, а должно 8 и -1.

Comment: у меня вышел такой код https://pastebin.com/Kw4C0QpH

Comment: def - это определение функции в python, // - целочисленное деление, поэтому строчки вычисления last будут `int last = first - 1 + nd / ndig;`

Comment: спасибо, программу понял, работает верно, но тоже на втором тесте выдает "Runtime error on test 2".

Comment: Код не проверяет валидность входных данных, но при условии `1 ≤ N, X ≤ 10^15` этого вроде и не требуется.

Comment: Да, увидел в pastebin тип int  - надо long long для всех, кроме ndig

Comment: переделал вот так - https://pastebin.com/A0SJYzVH. Теперь пишет на втором тесте wrong answer. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Семён Семёныч!! (с)   `long long int pages`  https://ideone.com/vfLa8Q

Comment: спасибо большое, все заработало!! кажется я просто слепой :)